# Pushing unique data into vector

Tags: c++, insert, unique, stdvector

I have the following data:

```
FolioA Name1 100
FolioA Name2 110
FolioA Name3 100
FolioB Name1 100
FolioB Name3 106
FolioC Name1 108
FolioC Name2 102
FolioC Name3 110
```

I want to only insert unique names(i.e. Name1, Name2 and Name3, each once) into

```
std::vector<std::string> name;
```

as I iterate through the data.

So, I have the following code where I have stored the data in a map called test:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, double> >test;
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, double > >::iterator it1 = test.begin(), end1 = test.end();
    while (it1 !=end1) {
        std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it2 = it1->second.begin(), end2=it1->second.end();
        **name.push_back(it2->first);**
        ++it2;
    }
    ++it1;
}
```

But, currently by pushing the data into name the way I am has 3 instances of Name1, 2 of Name2, and 3 of Name3, which is expected from my code. How do I fix it to only have unique names.

Comment: How would you chose which instance to include?

Comment: Do you have to have a `vector` of names?  I would suggest using a `set` of names for this instead.  If you have to have a vector, you can still insert first into a set, then move the objects into a `vector` using the constructor overload that takes `iterator`s.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I would pick the first instance of each, so if the vector already contains (Name1, Name2, Name3), then when it hits the 4th record, it identifies that the record already exists, so it skips it, and goes to the next record.

Comment: @Chad, can you post sample code

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since you want to keep the first instance for a given name, you will have to perform a name lookup at some point. A simple algorithm involving only your vector would be to can check if the the entry already exists using [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
std::vector<std::string> name;

....
if (std::find(name.begin(), name.end(), someName) == name.end()) {
  // someName not in name, add it
  name.push_back(someName);
}
```

But here you are performing a search each time you want to insert an element, and this (by itself) is up to `O(N)` complexity, giving `O(N*N)` for the whole algorithm. So you could optimize by using an intermediary container with fast look up, such as an `std::set` as suggested by @Chad and which has `O(logN)` complexity for look-up, giving `O(N*logN)` overall, or a hash container such as C++11's [std::unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), which has close to constant time look-up, giving ~O(N) overall complexity.

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<std::string> name_set;
....

// still need to search, since you want to keep 
// the first instance of each name, and not the last.
// But unordered_set performs the look-up at insertion,
// only inserting if someName not already in the set
name_set.insert(someName);
```

and then, following @Chad's example,

```
std::vector<std::string> name(names_set.begin(), name_set.end());
```

If you don't have C++11, hash map alternatives are `boost::hash_map` and `tr1::hash_map`.

Comment: aha, that sounds like it might do it. Can you post sample code as to how I would use it.

Comment: [Schlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm). I.e. `O(N*N)`. It works, but Chad's solution scales far better.

Comment: @MSalters, perhaps you can explain why you classify it the way you do. Chad's solution works too, but what is the mistake with the above.

Comment: @user1155299 the problem is that this algorithm isn't very efficient, i.e. it's complexity is a unnecessarily high high. I have provided a better example with some explanations.

Comment: @MSalters very true. Chad's solution doesn't solve the actual problem but gets very close. I have updated my answer with some explanations.

Comment: There is something escaping by understanding here. Why in the 1st and 2nd blocks of code the operator is != instead of ==? Shouldn't we insert in the case of not already having it inside the collection?

Comment: @sergiol Good catch! I was also misusing the set. All fixed now.

Comment: @user1155299 how could it work when you had an operator that does the exactly the opposite behavior you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use another map istead of a vector to have unique names.

std::map < std::string, double > name;

Answer (score 3):

You asked for sample code, so here's how I would have done it:

```
std::set<std::string> unique_names;

// ...
while (it1 !=end1)
{
    // ...
    // **name.push_back(it2->first);**
    unique_names.insert(it2->first);
}

std::vector<std::string> name(unique_names.begin(), unique_names.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not care which instance you want to enter into your data-structure, [std::set](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html) would server your purpose

Answer (score 2):

list has the ability to .sort() and then .unique(), which will provide you with .

you can iterate over it with an iterator and initialize it with initializer_list.

that data looks actually more like a struct to me:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct NODE_S {
    string name1, name2;
    int n;
} NODE_S NODE;

bool compare_NODE (NODE first, NODE second)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    if (first.name1 < second.name1) {
        return true;
    } else if (first.name2 < second.name2) {
        return true;
    } else if (first.n < second.n) {
        return true;
    } else { return false;}
}


bool readfile(list<NODE>& ln, string filepath) {
    std::ifstream filein;
    NODE n;
    filein.open(filepath.c_str(), std::iofstream::in);
    if (!filein.good()) {
        filein.close();
        std::cerr << "ERROR: unable to open file \"" << filepath << "\" or file is zero-length." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    do {
        filein >> n.name1 >> n.name2 >> n.name3 >> std::skipws;
        ln.push_back(n);
        ln.sort(compare_NODE);
        ln.unique();
        //add node to list

    } while (!filein.good()); //can use .eof here, but if bad disk blocks...
    filein.close();
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[], char * envp[]) {
    string filepath="somefile.txt";
    if (!readfile(filepath)) {
        return 1;
    }
    list<NODE>::iterator lni;
    for (lni = ln.begin(); lni != ln.end(); lni++) {
        std::cout<<lni->name1<<' '<<lni->name2<<' '<<lni->n<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/unique/

Comment: You'll want to move the `sort` and `unique` calls down, outside the loop. Now they're called once per `NODE`. BTW, the `typedef struct` thing hasn't been needed in 20 years.